# Вылетает программа при сознании экземпляра класса UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Столкнулся с одной неприятной ошибкой: при создании внутри `ViewController`’а экземпляра класса `UICollectionView`, программа крашится. Создаётся только экземпляр:

```
let cv = UICollectionView()
```

Больше никакие действия не совершаются

Comment: Крашиться в момент создания? Или вы что-то пытаетесь с делать еще?

Answer (score 1):

Создавать экземпляр класса `UICollectionView` необходимо с использованием конструктора `init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)`. Это один из двух доступных конструкторов, наряду с `init?(coder: NSCoder)`. Подробнее можно ознакомиться [тут](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init).